# HTTP request works in curl but fails with 503 in apps?

Tags: java, android, curl, adb, squid

I am hosting an api on my phone at localhost, and when I adb shell into the device at try a curl command to the localhost it works. But when I try to do it in java or kotlin the server returns a 503 and a weird error message in html?

This is the curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

This is the html error page that I receive:
[image: Error Page]

And this is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html><head>
 <meta type="copyright" content="Copyright (C) 1996-2018 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
 <style type="text/css"><!-- 
  /*
  * Copyright (C) 1996-2018 The Squid Software Foundation and contributors
  *
  * Squid software is distributed under GPLv2+ license and includes
  * contributions from numerous individuals and organizations.
  * Please see the COPYING and CONTRIBUTORS files for details.
  */
 
 /*
  Stylesheet for Squid Error pages
  Adapted from design by Free CSS Templates
  http://www.freecsstemplates.org
  Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License
 */
 
 /* Page basics */
 * {
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
 }
 
 html body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #efefef;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #1e1e1e;
 }
 
 /* Page displayed title area */
 #titles {
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    background: url('/squid-internal-static/icons/SN.png') no-repeat left;
 }
 
 /* initial title */
 #titles h1 {
    color: #000000;
 }
 #titles h2 {
    color: #000000;
 }
 
 /* special event: FTP success page titles */
 #titles ftpsuccess {
    background-color:#00ff00;
    width:100%;
 }
 
 /* Page displayed body content area */
 #content {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
 }
 
 /* General text */
 p {
 }
 
 /* error brief description */
 #error p {
 }
 
 /* some data which may have caused the problem */
 #data {
 }
 
 /* the error message received from the system or other software */
 #sysmsg {
 }
 
 pre {
 }
 
 /* special event: FTP / Gopher directory listing */
 #dirmsg {
     font-family: courier, monospace;
     color: black;
     font-size: 10pt;
 }
 #dirlisting {
     margin-left: 2%;
     margin-right: 2%;
 }
 #dirlisting tr.entry td.icon,td.filename,td.size,td.date {
     border-bottom: groove;
 }
 #dirlisting td.size {
     width: 50px;
     text-align: right;
     padding-right: 5px;
 }
 
 /* horizontal lines */
 hr {
    margin: 0;
 }
 
 /* page displayed footer area */
 #footer {
    font-size: 9px;
    padding-left: 10px;
 }
 
 
 body
 :lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; }
 :lang(he) { direction: rtl; }
  --></style>
 </head><body id=ERR_CONNECT_FAIL>
 <div id="titles">
 <h1>ERROR</h1>
 <h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
 </div>
 <hr>
 
 <div id="content">
 <p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8545/">http://127.0.0.1:8545/</a></p>
 
 <blockquote id="error">
 <p><b>Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed.</b></p>
 </blockquote>
 
 <p id="sysmsg">The system returned: <i>(111) Connection refused</i></p>
 
 <p>The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.</p>
 
 <p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster?subject=CacheErrorInfo%20-%20ERR_CONNECT_FAIL&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20lxasmap001.at.inside%0D%0AErrPage%3A%20ERR_CONNECT_FAIL%0D%0AErr%3A%20(111)%20Connection%20refused%0D%0ATimeStamp%3A%20Wed,%2001%20Jun%202022%2017%3A52%3A09%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClientIP%3A%2010.52.113.145%0D%0AServerIP%3A%20127.0.0.1%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0APOST%20%2F%20HTTP%2F1.1%0AContent-Type%3A%20application%2Fjson%0D%0AUser-Agent%3A%20Dalvik%2F2.1.0%20(Linux%3B%20U%3B%20Android%2012%3B%20Pixel%203%20Build%2FSP2A.220405.004)%0D%0AConnection%3A%20Keep-Alive%0D%0AAccept-Encoding%3A%20gzip%0D%0AContent-Length%3A%2067%0D%0AHost%3A%20127.0.0.1%3A8545%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A">webmaster</a>.</p>
 
 <br>
 </div>
 
 <hr>
 <div id="footer">
 <p>Generated Wed, 01 Jun 2022 17:52:09 GMT by lxasmap001.at.inside (squid/4.4)</p>
 <!-- ERR_CONNECT_FAIL -->
 </div>
 </body></html>
```

Comment: The error message comes from a Squid proxy, do you have a running Squid on your Android phone? If not I assume there is a proxy set in the Android network settings and the proxy is used even for 127.0.0.1 connections. For the request your Android phone then connects to the proxy and on the proxy 127.0.0.1 refers to the proxy server and not the server you are running locally on Android. You need to ignore the configured proxy in your Java/Kotlin code (as curl does by default).

Comment: @Robert Do you know how I can ignore the proxy, or outright disable it on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

To perform network operations in your application, your manifest must include the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Comment: I already added these. The request in its self works, just the server response differently. Could it be that the java http client misinterprets `127.0.0.1` and sends it to a different server? Because I don't get why curl produces a different result than the android app?

Comment: what is `lxasmap001.at.inside` ? do you have a proxy defined on the device?

Comment: I did not setup a proxy. That's why I am so confused. Maybe it is sending the request to some router and the router doesn't know what to do with it? I have never seen something like this. It happened now after I upgraded to android 12

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this IP in network_security_config.xml

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config